# What is the equivalent of NOW() from MySQL in GraphQL?

Tags: mysql, database, graphql

I have a create_date column in my database I want to enter the current time as the value. Is there an equivalent of `NOW()` in GraphQL?

Comment: GraphQL is not a database, there isn't an equivalent concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [psql's `now()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html).

Assign it like `create_date: "now()"`.